# WPF Change SplineThicknessKeyFrame value?

Tags: wpf, canvas

Im new in WPF, please if somebody can give me some tips to do this:

I need to move some images from to left or right, like in a coverflow (carousel, i can't use component as Dev Express, i have to do it for myself). And i need that if i maximize the window the "carousel" expand too and keep relation between margins of the images.

I try it moving the images in a Canvas, but when i maximize the window the Canvas dont do it and keep little.. I read and understand that i can't do that with a Canvas, so i do it putting the images on grids and changing its margin property, its works but when i maximize, the margin still is the same that when images are little and the aspect ratio is loose.

So my question is, how can i change the margin too when i maximize the window?

My code to move images using margin is:

```
<Storyboard Name="FlowIzq">
   <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="Image1" BeginTime="00:00:00">
<SplineThicknessKeyFrame    KeyTime="00:00:00"  Value="0,0,0,0"/>
<SplineThicknessKeyFrame    KeyTime="00:00:0.5" Value="-157, 0,157,0"/>
</ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

</Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
```

I think i need to change the value of all SplineThicknessKeyFrame, but how i do that?

I hope explain it well and somebody can help me (sorry for my english) if something is not understood i explain it again.

Peace,
Rob.

Answer (score 0):

4 years later I found myself needing a similar storyboard so I thought I'd share what I ended up with. Hopefully it helps someone else in 4 more years.

```
<Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
               <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard >    
                     <DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                       From="1"
                                       To="0"
                                       Duration="0:0:1">
                     </DoubleAnimation>    
                     <DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                       From="0"
                                       To="1"
                                       Duration="0:0:1"
                                       BeginTime="0:0:1">
                     </DoubleAnimation>

                     <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="00:00:1">
                        <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:1" Value="0,0,500,0" />
                     </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                     <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="00:00:1">
                        <DiscreteThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:1.0" Value="0,0,-550,0" />
                     </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                     <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="00:00:1" BeginTime="0:0:1">
                        <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:1.0" Value="0" />
                     </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>    
                  </Storyboard>
               </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>    
         </Grid.Triggers>
```

Just replace `Grid.Triggers` with your `Control.Triggers` and the `EventTrigger.RoutedEvent` to the event that makes sense to you.